# Is mutating accumulator in reduce function considered bad practice?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm new to functional programming and I'm trying rewrite some code to make it more functional-ish to grasp the concepts. Just now I've discovered `Array.reduce()` function and used it to create an object of arrays of combinations (I've used `for` loop before that). However, I'm not sure about something. Look at this code:

```
const sortedCombinations = combinations.reduce(
    (accum, comb) => {
        if(accum[comb.strength]) {
            accum[comb.strength].push(comb);
        } else {
            accum[comb.strength] = [comb];
        }

        return accum;
    },
    {}
);
```

Obviously, this function mutates its argument `accum`, so it is not considered pure. On the other hand, the reduce function, if I understand it correctly, discards accumulator from every iteration and doesn't use it after calling callback function. Still, it's not a pure function. I can rewrite it like this:

```
const sortedCombinations = combinations.reduce(
    (accum, comb) => {
        const tempAccum = Object.assign({}, accum);
        if(tempAccum[comb.strength]) {
            tempAccum[comb.strength].push(comb);
        } else {
            tempAccum[comb.strength] = [comb];
        }

        return tempAccum;
    },
    {}
);
```

Now, in my understanding, this function is considered pure. However, it creates a new object every iteration, which consumes some time, and, obviously, memory.

So the question is: which variant is better and why? Is purity really so important that I should sacrifice performance and memory to achieve it? Or maybe I'm missing something, and there is some better option?

Comment: Why do you think modifying the accumulator is a problem in a case where you passed in the original accumulator and it exists nowhere else? It's an issue if you're creating external side-effects (just because functional tools with side-effects are evil), but there is no externally visible side-effects as written. Sure, it's a little impure (and probably better off done with a simple `for` loop), but if you're using `reduce` anyway? Meh.

Comment: why not use `({ ...accum }, comb)` as parameters? instantly a copy ...

Comment: Local mutations are less harmful than those leaking into the global scope. However, even local ones can bite back as soon as things get more complicated. This recently happened to me and I spent 3 hours fixing it..

Comment: "*Is purity really so important that I should sacrifice performance and memory to achieve it?*" - no, definitely not. But you shouldn't call your code "functional" any more when you violate purity and immutability.

Comment: Oh pish posh, you don't need to be perfectly functional to be functional any more than having functions that don't belong to a class make your OOP no longer OOP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating a new object on every iteration is common practice, and sometimes recommended, despite any potential performance issues.

(EDIT:) I guess that is because if you want to have only one general advice, then copying less likely causes
problems than mutating. The performance starts to become a "real" issue
if you have more than lets say about 1000 iterations. *(For more details see my update below)*

You can make your function pure in e.g. in this way:

```
const sortedCombinations = combinations.reduce(
    (accum, comb) => {
        return {
            ...accum,
            [comb.strength]: [
                ...(accum[comb.strength] || []),
                comb
            ]
        };
    },
    {}
);
```

Purity might become more important if your state and reducer is defined somewhere else:

```
const myReducer = (accum, comb) => {
    return {
        ...accum,
        [comb.strength]: [
            ...(accum[comb.strength] || []),
            comb
        ]
    };
};

const initialState = {};
const sortedCombinations = combinations.reduce( myReducer, initialState );
const otherSortedCombinations = otherCombinations.reduce( myReducer, initialState );
const otherThing = otherList.reduce( otherReducer, initialState );
```

### Update (2021-08-22):

#### preface to this update

As stated in the comments (and also mentioned in the question), of course copying on every iteration is less performant.

And I admit that in many cases, *technically* I can't see any disadvantages of mutating the accumulator (if you know what you are doing!).

Actually, thinking about it again, inspired from the comments and other answers,
I changed my mind a bit, and will consider mutating more often now, maybe at least
where I don't see any risk that e.g. somebody else misunderstands my code later.

But then again the question was explicitly about purity ... anyway, so here some more details:

#### purity

*(Disclaimer: I must admit here that I know about [React](https://reactjs.org), but I don't know much about "the world of functional programming"
and their arguments about the advantages, e.g. in Haskell)*

Using this "pure" approach **is a tradeoff**. You loose performance, and you win easier understandable and less coupled code.

E.g. in [React](https://reactjs.org), with many nested Components, you can always rely on the consistent state of the current component.
You know it will not be changed anywhere outside, except if you have passed down some 'onChange' callback explicitly.

If you define an object, you know for sure it will **always stay unchanged**.
If you need a modified version, you would have an new variable assignment,
this way it is obvious that you are working with a new version of the data
from here down, and any code that might use the old object will not be affected.:

```
const myObject = { a1: 1, a2: 2, a3: 3 };        <-- stays unchanged

// ... much other code ...

const myOtherObject = modifySomehow( myObject ); <-- new version of the data
```

#### Pros, Cons, and Caveats

I couldn't give a general advice which way (copy or mutate) is "the better one".
Mutating is more performant, but can cause lots of hard-to-debug problems, if you aren't absolutely sure what's happening.
At least in somewhat complex scenarios.

##### 1. problem with non-pure reducer

As already mentioned in my original answer, a **non-pure** function
might unintentionally change some outside state:

```
var initialValue = { a1: 1, a2: 2, a3: 3, a4: 4 };
var newKeys = [ 'n1', 'n2', 'n3' ];

var result = newKeys.reduce( (acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = 'new ' + key;
    return acc
}, initialValue);

console.log( 'result:', result );             // We are interested in the 'result',
console.log( 'initialValue:', initialValue ); // but the initialValue has also changed.
```

Somebody might argue that you can copy the initial value beforehand:

```
var result = newKeys.reduce( (acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = 'new ' + key;
    return acc
}, { ...initialValue }); // <-- copy beforehand
```

But this might be even less efficient in cases where e.g. the object is very big and nested,
the reducer is called often, and maybe there are multiple conditionally used small modifications
inside the reducer, which are only changing little.
(think of [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) in React,
or the [Redux reducer](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#writing-reducers))

##### 2. shallow copies

An other answer stated correctly that even with the *supposedly* pure approach there might **still be a reference** to the original object.
And this is indeed something to be aware of, but the problems arise only if you do not follow this 'immutable' approach **consequently** enough:

```
var initialValue = { a1: { value: '11'}, a2: { value: '22'} }; // <-- an object with nested 'non-primitive' values

var newObject = Object.keys(initialValue).reduce( (acc, key) => {
    return {
        ...acc,
        ['newkey_' + key]: initialValue[key], // <-- copies a reference to the original object
    };
}, {}); // <-- starting with empty new object, expected to be 'pure'

newObject.newkey_a1.value = 'new ref value'; // <-- changes the value of the reference
console.log( initialValue.a1 ); // <-- initialValue has changed as well
```

This is not a problem, if it is taken care that no references are copied (which might be not trivial sometimes):

```
var initialValue = { a1: { value: '11'}, a2: { value: '22'} };
var newObject = Object.keys(initialValue).reduce( (acc, key) => {
    return {
        ...acc,
        ['newkey_' + key]: { value: initialValue[key].value }, // <-- copies the value
    };
}, {});

newObject.newkey_a1.value = 'new ref value';
console.log( initialValue.a1 ); // <-- initialValue has not changed
```

##### 3. performance

The performance is no problem with a few elements, but if the object has several thousand items, the performance becomes indeed a significant issue:

```
// create a large object
var myObject = {}; for( var i=0; i < 10000; i++ ){ myObject['key' + i] = i; } 

// copying 10000 items takes seconds (increasing exponentially!)
// (create a new object 10000 times, with each 1,2,3,...,10000 properties)
console.time('copy')
var result = Object.keys(myObject).reduce( (acc, key)=>{
    return {
        ...acc,
        [key]: myObject[key] * 2
    };
}, {});
console.timeEnd('copy');

// mutating 10000 items takes milliseconds (increasing linearly)
console.time('mutate')
var result = Object.keys(myObject).reduce( (acc, key)=>{
    acc[key] = myObject[key] * 2;
    return acc;
}, {});
console.timeEnd('mutate');
```

Comment: If you control the accumulator, i.e., you have created it inline as in your first example, you 100% should always mutate. The reason why involves understanding the runtime of the code. **Mutation** - The runtime is O(n), where n is the length of the list. The cost of a mutation, while it does exist, is essentially O(1). **Copy** - The runtime is O(n * m), where n is the length of the list again, and m is the length of the keys being copied within the object. Especially if your object's number of keys is growing as you iterate, this can effectively be O(n^2).

Answer (score 14):

**TL; DR:** It isn't if you own the accumulator.

---

It's quite common in JavaScript to use the spread operator to create nice looking one-liner reducing functions. Developers often claim that it also makes their functions pure in the process.

```js
const foo = xs => xs.reduce((acc, x) => ({...acc, [x.a]: x}), {});
//------------------------------------------------------------^
//                                                   (initial acc value)
```

But let's think about it for a second... What could possibly go wrong if you mutated `acc`? e.g.,

```js
const foo = xs => xs.reduce((acc, x) => {
  acc[x.a] = x;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Absolutely nothing.

The initial value of `acc` is an empty literal object created on the fly. Using the spread operator is only a "cosmetic" choice at this point. Both functions are pure.

**Immutability is a trait not a process per se.** Meaning that cloning data to achieve immutability is most likely both a naive and inefficient approach to it. Most people forget that the spread operator only does a shallow clone anyway!

I wrote this [article](https://gist.github.com/customcommander/97eb4b3f1600773db59406d39f3f9cd7) a little while ago where I claim that mutation and functional programming don't have to be mutually exclusive and I also show that using the spread operator isn't a trivial choice to make.

Comment: _functional programming don't have to be mutually exclusive_ - this is a daring stance! Mutations introduce time into your program. Similar to `this` they are a sort of implicit state parameter you have to take into account. Mutations hamper local and equational reasoning and I think also associativity, which is the most important law in FP that maintains the algebraic structure of many FP idioms.

Comment: @scriptum I know! ;) However it's like saying _"eval is evil"_ no matter the use case. Nope it's not _always_ evil and you've got to know what you're doing for sure. The second version of `foo` is pure IMHO. The reducing function does mutate the accumulator but we've got to recognise that it is not a harmful mutation at all. This is pragmatic functional programming I'll give you that.