# How to implement memoization with "pure" Functional Programming in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

In all the examples I can find on memoization / internal function cache in Functional Programming in JavaScript, the examples are either mutating or reassigning the cache.

Here's an example taken from https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-memoization-in-javascript#toc-a-functional-approach

```
function memoizer(fun){
    let cache = {}
    return function (n){
        if (cache[n] != undefined ) {
          return cache[n]
        } else {
          let result = fun(n)
          cache[n] = result
          return result
        }
    }
}
```

The only tiny improvement I can come up with is to use reassigning instead of mutating the cache object:

```
function memoizer(fun){
    let cache = {}
    return function (n){
        if (cache[n] != undefined ) {
          return cache[n]
        } else {
          let result = fun(n)
          cache = {... cache, [n]: result}
          return result
        }
    }
}
```

But my question is how to do this in a "pure" functional way, without mutations or reassigning a let/var?

Comment: Re-creating the whole cache seems pretty inefficient.

Comment: You would need to wrap the function so that it takes a tuple of old cache and arguments and returns another tuple of new cache and result. This makes it very cumbersome to use, but it's possible.

Comment: I'm not saying that there's no place on SO for interesting puzzle questions (not downvoting or VTC this), but on a practical level isn't this kinda just pure wankery? Your function (and by construction all the functions you feed it) will always return the same value for the same input.

Comment: I'd use a lazy unfold that represents the entire result set (codomain) of your function but only lazily, i.e. on demand evaluated. I think this is the mechanism used in purely functional programming. However, I never implemented it so its just a teaser.

Comment: @scriptum Thanks, but can't really find much about "lazy unload" but did find this about "unload" https://ramdajs.com/docs/#unfold and https://nabilhassein.github.io/blog/unfold/ - but you're talking about doing it lazily / on demand. Can you give a little more info on what you had in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This partially answers the question how to memoize all kind of functions in a purely functional manner. The solution is completely different from your imperative one and the code is not production ready but just a proof of concept. Please note that I am also a rookie on this subject.

The answer is partial, because I am only going to show a memoize function whose domain (arguments) are integers. A more advanced polymorphic memoization function can handle all kinds of argument types and also recursive functions.

The basic idea is to have a function that operates on an infinite list of integers. A list can be only infinite if it is non-strictly evaluated, that is to say only evaluated when needed and only just enough. We will later see that non-strictness is not enough for memoization, we need proper lazy evaluation.

In the first example I am going to use explicit thunks (e.g. nullary functions of shape `() => "do something"` for the sake of simplicity:

```js
// INFINITE LIST

// we only mimick such a type

const iterate = f => {
  const go = x =>
    [x, () => go(f(x))];

  return go;
};

// Functor

const map = f => {
  const go = ([x, thunk]) =>
    [log(f(x)), () => go(thunk())];

  return go;
};

// element lookup

const lookup = ([x, thunk]) => i =>
  i === 0
    ? x
    : lookup(thunk()) (i - 1);

// memoization

const memoize = f =>
  lookup(
    map(f)
      (iterate(x => x + 1) (0)));

// auxiliary function

const log = x => (console.log(x), x);

const fib = n => {
  return n > 1
    ? fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
    : n;
}

// MAIN

const foo = memoize(fib);

console.log("yields:", foo(6)); // logs 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8
console.log("yields:", foo(6)); // logs 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8
```

This works with an infinite sequence of fibonacci numbers and yields the expected result, but there is still no memoization. Right now it is just a cumbersome way to calculate places from the fibunacci sequence.

While this algorithm is non-strict, we need proper lazy evaluation as already mentioned. Lazy evaluation means non-strict evaluation with sharing of once computed thunks. We can mimic lazy evaluation with the native `Proxy` type in Javascript. Please note that the explicit thunks from the above example are now replaced with implicit ones, i.e. you don't need to call (`thunk()`) but just use them as if they were ordinary values. Here is a working sketch:

```js
const NULL = "null";

const THUNK = "thunk";

const thunk = thunk =>
  new Proxy(thunk, new ThunkProxy());

class ThunkProxy {
  constructor() {
    this.memo = NULL;
  }

  apply(g, that, args) {
    if (this.memo === NULL) {
      this.memo = g();

      while (this.memo && this.memo[THUNK] === true)
        this.memo = this.memo.valueOf();
    }

    return this.memo(...args);
  }

  get(g, k) {
    if (k === THUNK)
      return true;

    else if (this.memo === NULL) {
      this.memo = g();
      
      while (this.memo && this.memo[THUNK] === true)
        this.memo = this.memo.valueOf();
    }

    if (k === "valueOf")
      return () => this.memo

    else if (k === "toString")
      return () => this.memo.toString();

    else if (k === Symbol.toStringTag)
      return Object.prototype.toString.call(this.memo).slice(8, -1);

    while (this.memo[k] && this.memo[k] [THUNK] === true)
      this.memo[k] = this.memo[k].valueOf();

    if (typeof this.memo[k] === "function")
      return this.memo[k].bind(this.memo);

    else return this.memo[k];
  }

  has(g, k) {
    if (k === THUNK)
      return true;

    else if (this.memo === NULL) {
      this.memo = g();

      while (this.memo && this.memo[THUNK] === true)
        this.memo = this.memo.valueOf();
    }

    return k in this.memo;
  }
}

const iterate = f => {
  const go = x =>
    [x, thunk(() => go(f(x)))];

  return go;
};

const lookup = ([head, tail]) => i =>
  i === 0
    ? head
    : lookup(tail) (i - 1);

const map = f => {
  const go = ([head, tail]) =>
    [log(f(head)), thunk(() => go(tail))];

  return go;
};

const memoize = f =>
  lookup(
    map(f)
      (iterate(x => x + 1) (0)));

const log = x => (console.log(x), x);

const fib = n => {
  return n > 1
    ? fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
    : n;
}

const foo = memoize(fib);

console.log("yields:", foo(6)); // logs 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, "yields: 8"
console.log("yields:", foo(6)); // logs "yields: 8"
console.log("yields:", foo(10)); // logs 13, 21, 34, 55, "yields: 55"
```

Finally we've achieved the desired memoization effect, but the way I mimic lazy evaluation in Javascript is impure as well - I am just cheating. In a purely functional language like Haskell, however, lazy evaluation is an implementation detail of the language and thus not part of the syntax you actually use. This way the language itself remains pure.

Please note that `fib` is a recursive function and `memoize` does not handle the recursive steps but only intermediate and the final result.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for taking the time to write this great answer. When I saw you were using a class I was first a bit skeptical, but the point you state in the 2nd last paragraph  made me finally understand that the reason you can't do this 100% purely functional in JS is that it is an implementation details in a pure language such as Haskell. Thinking about that opens a new world of possibilities. I'll need some time to read and re-read your answer, to fully understand it. Thanks again, much appreciated!!

Comment: I've used the `ThunkProxy` class in more complex scenarios (a lazy list monad transformer, for instance) and it works quite reliable. There is an issue with the weak head normal form (WHNF), though. AFAIK every bare thunk (unevaluated sub-expression) in Haskell is immediately evaluated into WHNF, i.e. `[1, thunk]` remains as is, but `thunk` is automatically evaluated regarding the outermost layer. So `thunk` is evaluated to `[1, thunk]`, for instance, but not any further. `ThunkProxy` does not mimic this behaior correctly. You have to do it manually sometimes. It is too lazy so to speak.

Comment: Please also note that I used a simplified version of `ThunkProxy`. The full implementation is available on Github via my profile page.

Answer (score 5):

With the [definition of a "pure function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) being:

> In computer programming, a pure function is a function that has the
> following properties:[1][2]
>
> Its return value is the same for the same arguments (no variation with
> local static variables, non-local variables, mutable reference
> arguments or input streams from I/O devices).
> Its evaluation has no
> side effects (no mutation of local static variables, non-local
> variables, mutable reference arguments or I/O streams).

---

I think we can see that what you have is a pure function, if the same values are passed to the function, you will always get the same result; there is nothing in that method that would be affected by any external state beyond it –– that is unless the passed `fun` argument isn't pure, but that isn't an issue with your `memoizer` method itself.

**EDIT**
Because the `cache` object is not a static variable, mutating it does not violate any of the rules of what makes a pure function pure.
[Definition of "side effects"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) as used by Wikipedia in the explanation above:

> In computer science, an operation, function or expression is said to
> have a side effect if it modifies some state variable value(s) outside
> its local environment, that is to say has an observable effect besides
> returning a value (the main effect) to the invoker of the operation.

Comment: There's mutation of the `cache` variable, that violates the "no mutation" restriction.

Comment: "*Because the cache object is not a static variable, mutating it does not violate any of the rules of what makes a pure function pure.*" - no, that has nothing to do with it. Mutating *any* non-local state is problematic, regardless whether it's "static" or "global" or something else.

Comment: @Bergi I take your point, I was trying to bridge the gap between what Barmar has said and what was on the wikipedia definition.

Comment: The function might be pure, but like @Barmar mentioned it violates the "no mutation" restriction. My question is how to change this function so that it does not violate any of the functional programming principles.

Comment: @Dac0d3r I think people are misunderstanding what the "no mutation" restriction is. That is referring to mutating things outside the scope of the function – thereby potentially providing a different result with the same inputs. Please see [this heavily upvotted SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58749249/2983609) about function purity.

Answer (score 2):

```
(define (fib-memo n memo k)
  (let ((p (assv n memo)))
    (if p
        (let ((v (cdr p)))
          (k v memo))
        (fib-memo (- n 1) memo
                  (lambda (v1 memo^)
                    (fib-memo (- n 2) memo^
                              (lambda (v2 memo^^)
                                (let ((v (+ v1 v2)))
                                  (k v (cons (cons n v) memo^^))))))))))
(define (fib n)
  (fib-memo n '((1 . 1) (0 . 0)) (lambda (v memo) v)))
```

The Scheme code above is a purely functional memoized version of fibonacci using continuation-passing style to accumulate information as the computation progresses.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the variable `cache` remains private to the function I can't think of anything that could go wrong by mutating it. Incidentally recreating a new cache object isn't helpful because you do re-assign to the same reference anyway.

You *have to* update the cache somehow for your memoizer to be useful. You just need to make sure you're doing it in a safe way. Don't read or write from a global cache for example.

I'm sure there are ways to do this with monads (or other functional programming constructs) but I'd don't feel qualified enough to talk about it. Keeping your function pure (and by the look of it it is) is already a big win in my opinion.

Note that in the event where applying the memoized function to *n* does return `undefined` (or `null`) this would never be cached because with `cache[n] != undefined` you cannot differentiate between a call you didn't make yet and a call that genuinely returned `undefined`. You should perhaps do something like `cache.hasOwnProperty(n)` instead.

See also [Is mutating accumulator in reduce function considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63727586/1244884)

---

An alternative implementation of `memoizer` could use `Function#bind` but admittedly this may not be a better way of doing it.

```js
const memoizer =
  fn =>
    ((cache, n) =>
      n in cache
        ? cache[n]
        : cache[n] = fn(n)).bind(null, {});
```

Comment: `bind` is not better, just more confusing.

Comment: "*Don't read or write from a global cache for example.*" - why do you think that would be unsafe?

Comment: @Bergi If the cache is publicly available that would be unsafe in my opinion as you cannot guarantee (or not easily guarantee) that it hadn't been tampered with. (If that's a useful addition to make to the post I can certainly add that.) As for bind I do agree (and I did mention it) but I shared the alternative in case OP finds it useful.

Answer (score 0):

In a pure functional language we are not allowed to mutate values. However, it is possible to change the state of a variable from uninitialized to initialized during execution. This can be leveraged for memorization.

We provide an example of how to implement the Fibonacci Recursion in the pure functional language nix below.

As lists are lazily evaluated in nix, we can incrementally initialize values in a list, and compute them on first access. Subsequent accesses do not re-trigger computation but used the "cached" value:

```hs
let 
  # iota n = [1 2 3 ... n]
  iota = n: if n == 0 then [] else (iota (n - 1)) ++ [n];
  fib = n: 
    let
      results = map (x: g x) ([0] ++ (iota n));
      f = x:
        if x <= 2 then 1 else
          (elemAt results (x - 1)) + (elemAt results (x - 2));
      g = x: trace "Called f ${toString x}" (f x);
    in
      g n;
in 
  fib 5;
```

```
; nix repl -f fib.nix
trace: Called f 5
trace: Called f 4
trace: Called f 3
trace: Called f 2
trace: Called f 1
5
```

Code example with tests is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/HeinrichHartmann/Algorithms-in-Nix/blob/519b1ab44cc0d6d38aefea76e7978aebe4b8c3fc/algorithms.nix#L31-L44)